# Unable to connect Google Compute Engine instance via SSH in browser

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, google-compute-engine, mail-server, dovecot

i am new to google cloud,i just deployed my first instance it was working fine till yesterday, i used last time to set email server using this tutorial [email server](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/4/), but now i am unable to connect ssh in browser and also with google cloud sdk in terminal.

Website is running fine,I don't know what happened Please help

the error message in browser

```
Connection Failed, and we are unable to connect VM on port 22.
```

the error message in terminal

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

And serial console output its shows

```
Jul 8 10:09:26 Instance sshd[10103]: error: Could not load host key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: User username from 0.0.0.0 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: input_userauth_request: invalid user username [preauth] Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: Connection closed by 0.0.0.0 [preauth] –
```

Comment: Looks like you have the same issue as referenced in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293954/cannot-connect-to-google-compute-engine-instance-via-ssh-in-browser

Comment: See also the same question on SF, where you did get an answer http://serverfault.com/questions/704330/unable-to-connect-google-compute-engine-instance-via-ssh-in-browser/704405#704405