# Can't SSH connect to Google Cloud Compute Engine after rebooting

Tags: ssh, centos, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-console

I just restarted my google cloud compute engine instance and now I cannot SSH login to it. Before restarting, it worked fine. I tried fully stopping it and then starting again. There was a webserver on it and if I try to access any API method, I get timeout.

If I try to login from console website:
[image]

If I try to login from terminal:

```
ssh: connect to host 104.197.20.65 port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293954/cannot-connect-to-google-compute-engine-instance-via-ssh-in-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to Google Compute Engine instance via SSH in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293954/cannot-connect-to-google-compute-engine-instance-via-ssh-in-browser)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggest the first thing to do is check the firewall rules. There must be a rule allowing connections from any ip (0.0.0.0/0) through the port 22. I assume that your instance's ssh was working before, so it can be two things.

1. The rule is being applied to a certain network, and the network configuration of the VM was changed when it was shutted down.
2. The rule is not being applied to the VM, maybe it is in a subnetwork, closing the communication.

To simplify the solution:

A- Add a network tag to your VM. (Ex. ssh-conn)
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/add-remove-network-tags

B- Create a rule to allow connections from any ip and apply it to the network tag previously created.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried lots of way but none of them work.

But the way below is work for me:

1. Connect to instance by serial console.
2. `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, delete the hash tag before `Port 22`, like this:

```
Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
```

Hope it work for you too.